# Show that the number 9 divides the number $ m$ if and only if the sum of the digits of the number $ m $ is divisible by 9.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Show that the number 9 divides the number $ m$ if and only if the sum of the digits of the number $ m $ is divisible by 9.

Show that the number 3 divides the number $ m$ if and only if the sum of the digits of the number $ m $ is divisible by 3.

Are semigroup and monoid theory could be useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $\displaystyle10\equiv1\pmod9, 10^r\equiv1$ for integer $r\ge0$

$$\implies\sum_{r=0}^na_r10^r\equiv\sum_{r=0}^na_r\pmod9$$

More generally for base $b,$  as $\displaystyle b\equiv1\pmod{b-1}\implies b^r\equiv1$ for integer $r\ge0$

$$\sum_{r=0}^na_rb^r\equiv\sum_{r=0}^na_r\pmod{b-1}$$

Comment: Ok, but how to show in the opposite direction?

Comment: @keri, I think, this conclusion establishes both the direction simultaneously

Comment: and how it looks like wtih 3?

Comment: @keri, We can safely replace $\pmod9$ with $\pmod3$

Comment: true! I see it:) But I'm still not sure if it works that if m is divided by 9 then sum of number m is divided by 9?