# Let $a$ be a three digit integer number with digits $x; y; z $(in that order). Prove that $a$ is divisible by 9...

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Let $a$ be a three digit integer number with digits $x; y; z $(in that order). Prove that $a$ is divisible by 9 if and only if $x + y + z$ is divisible by 9.

Following a proof of this:
Let $a; b; d; k$ be integers such that $a = dk + b$. Prove that $a$ is divisible by $d$ if and
only if $b$ is divisible by $d$.

Comment: Well let $a=100x+10y+z$ with $0\leq x,y,z\leq 9$ and $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$. The sum of its digits is $s=x+y+z$. Notice that $a-s=99x+9y=9(11x+y)\Leftrightarrow 9|(a-s)$. Can you finish?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that the number 9 divides the number $ m$ if and only if the sum of the digits of the number $ m $ is divisible by 9.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830641/show-that-the-number-9-divides-the-number-m-if-and-only-if-the-sum-of-the-dig)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you pick 100, 10, and 1 as the coefficients of x,y,z?

Comment: The number $\overline {xyz}$ in base 10 evaluates to $100x + 10y + z$, the same way the number $3236$ in base 10 evaluates to $1000\times 3 + 100 \times 2 + 10 \times 3 + 6$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the number $xyz$ equals $$100x+10y+z = 9(11x+y)+(x+y+z),$$
which is clearly divisible by $9$ if and only if $x+y+z$ is.